# How do I assign the innerHTML of a DIV to an array of DIVs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am working with an HTMLCollection that needs to be converted to an array so that it can be spliced. Currently I am converting the Collection to an array by using Array.from()

`var array = Array.from(element.children)`

Then I splice the array.

`array.splice(0, index);`

Now I need to set the innerHTML of the above mentioned element to the spliced array.

`element.innerHTML = array.join()`

This only returns [object HTMLDivElement] [objectHTMLDivElement]

Note: this needs to be very efficient which is why I am avoiding for-loops. Reason being that the Collection will contain around 10000 divs

Edit: I have tried working with Array.prototype.splice.call(element.children, arguments)
Only to receive an error saying that the elements.length property is read-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can NOT totally avoid loops. Use [Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

```js
let element = document.getElementById("x");
var array = Array.from(element.children)

array.splice(0, 2);
element.innerHTML = array.map(e => e.outerHTML).join()
```

```html
<div id="x">
  <span>span 1</span>
  <span>span 2</span>
  <span>span 3</span>
</div>
```

Also, as you are trying to remove first few elements. you can also try following

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("#x > *");
let index = 2;
let i = 0;
while (i < index) {
  elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
  i++;
}
```

```html
<div id="x">
  <span>span 1</span>
  <span>span 2</span>
  <span>span 3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to avoid loops in this case. Somehow you need to go through your array and manipulate the data for each element, and the only way is with loops.

In your case, since you're changing something for each element rather than fetching data from each element, I'd suggest using the map-function. This creates a new array with the results you're looking for, and in your case I think it's the fastest way.

```
let arraySplice = array.splice(0, index);
arraySplice.map( (element) => {
  // Do something with your element here
  console.log(element);
})
```

I'm suspecting though, that there's a better way to solve your problem than to manipulate the innerHTML of each div when there's so many divs. Lazy loading and/or querying batches through an API might help your case.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that, but thanks for your answer, I guess the best would be to implement a form of lazy loading. I was just thinking there was a faster way to do this.

Comment: I'm yet to see a system that lists 10k+ of anything without any form of pagination. The problem is that everything you see on screen must be kept in memory, so you want to make sure it runs smooth even on older tech and/or smartphones with low memory.